# Using split to break a long equation

Tags: equations, line-breaking, amsmath

I am trying to break a long equation over multiple lines. It is here as follows:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
L(\textbf{q})=&\prod_{t=0}^{36}{q_{1}^{iB(t)sB(t+1)+iC(t)sC(t+1)}\\
&\quad\cdot q_{2}^{i(t)sA(t+1)+(iA(t)+iC(t))sB(t+1)+(iA(t)+iB(t))sC(t+1)}\\
&\quad\cdot(1-q_{2}^{i(t)})^{sA(t)-sA(t+1)}\\
&\quad\cdot(1-q_{1}^{iB(t)}q_{2}^{iA(t)+iC(t)})^{sB(t)-sB(t+1)}\\
&\quad\cdot(1-q_{1}^{iC(t)}q_{2}^{iA(t)+iB(t)})^{sC(t)-sC(t+1)}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

But when I try and pdflatex the file, I get `!Missing }` inserted. And it doesn't run. I don't know why it's trying to put in extra brackets when they are not needed. And the file runs without the split environment (but I need to put it in since otherwise the equation flows off the page)

Any help??

Comment: Remove first `{` in `{q_{1}^{`, first line and the last `}` in `-sC(t+1)}}` last line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: You can make this much easier by replacing all the exponents
with some simple notations and explain them separately.

Comment: It's a common misconception to think that one has to write `\prod_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}}`; while the braces for the limits are necessary, those around `a_{i}` aren't and actually *shouldn't* be used.

Comment: Also, just so you know, it's best to use `\mathbf{q}` to get a bold upright q in math. For instance, if this equation was inside a theorem whose text was set in italic, the `\textbf{q}` would render as a bold italic q; but a `\mathbf{q}` would still render as a bold upright q.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of your code. You don't need to wrap the product itself into `{}`. For real grouping I used curly braces.

**Implementation**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        L(\bm{q})
        &= \prod\limits_{t=0}^{36} \Bigl\{ q_{1}^{iB(t)sB(t+1)+iC(t)sC(t+1)} \\
        &\quad \cdot q_{2}^{i(t)sA(t+1)+(iA(t)+iC(t))sB(t+1)+(iA(t)+iB(t))sC(t+1)} \\
        &\quad \cdot (1-q_{2}^{i(t)})^{sA(t)-sA(t+1)} \\
        &\quad \cdot (1-q_{1}^{iB(t)}q_{2}^{iA(t)+iC(t)})^{sB(t)-sB(t+1)} \\
        &\quad \cdot (1-q_{1}^{iC(t)}q_{2}^{iA(t)+iB(t)})^{sC(t)-sC(t+1)} \Bigr\}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

> [image: img]

Comment: I would align the subsequent factors under the first factor, not the `\prod`.

Comment: I like your suggestion, but according to the question, this is what OP wanted.